# GitHub oAuth apps: What's the most granular scope to get access to Pull Requests?

Tags: github, github-api, octokit, github-oauth

I'm reading the [documentation on Scopes for OAuth Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) and it's not clear to me if it's possible to grant read access to private repos, without providing write access.

The `repo` scope grants full access to read and write everything. This works but it's more permissive than what we would like.

The scope `public_repo` is only for public repos as its name suggests, and I'm not sure if `read:repo_hook` is what I need or not.

What's the best suited scope for my use case of reading pull request by passing a commit hash as a parameter to Octokit?

Answer (score 1):

For OAuth apps, the most granular scope is `repo` or `public_repo`, depending on whether you need access to all repositories or only public ones.

If you want more granular permissions, you need to use GitHub Apps, which also have OAuth featues (GitHub calls these user-to-server tokens):
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/identifying-and-authorizing-users-for-github-apps.

GitHub Apps need to be installed by users on repositories in order to grant access, and they have a `pull_request` read or write permission, depending on what you need.